# CKFinder popup onbeforeunload javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, ckfinder

I'm currently working with CKFinder to upload images to a web app (and so on).
Now the problem is, there is no callback when the window closes:
With that I mean something like the javascript "onbeforeunload" event. The popup function only returns the api, and the api only contains the document and not the window.

I've looked through the docs and found a "selectActionFunction", but no sign of a "cancelActionFunction" or something similar.

http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.config.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end I didn't really find a solution within ckfinder, but since I was already working with jquery ui I just opened the ckFinder in a ui dialog box. Which gives me the ability to add a callback to the close button.

Maybe it is possible to add a cancel callback through the skins, but I chose the quick way of ui dialogs. (The only skinning I tend to do is in CSS, which is more then enough most of times)

Anyway, I hope this helps someone else too.